# Mock an internal variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to check the result of a function with sum of two numbers without having a return statement:

```
function sum(a,b){
var res = a+b;
return true;
}

test('sum of numbers', () => {
expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(res)
});
```

How to get the value of the `res` variable in my test?

Comment: If your function has no side-effects, and returns nothing, what exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: The test should be `expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3)` and your function does not return anything

Comment: Im trying to test an internal variable value. The funtion will just return true. But in my test I need to mock and get "res" variable value. How to do this?

Comment: That test sounds virtually meaningless, as much as `var res = a+b;` has no effect and can be removed. What are you really trying to do here? If this is a stub/simplification of some less pointless code, you have probably oversimplified and should provide more context.

Comment: You can't because of scope. Tests should not be checking individual variables, it should be testing the outcome.

Comment: Its a requirement in my project. I have to test an internal variable value inside a function.

Comment: Or you are misreading the requirement

Comment: Is it possible to use spy or mock function to do this? Is there any way I can get "res" value in my test?

Comment: No..............

Comment: You've either misunderstood the requirement, misrepresented it here or simply shouldn't be using the project in question. The test case for the current implementation is `expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(true)` and you can delete the line where `res` is calculated entirely (the only observable behaviour would be if it threw an error, and I don't think there's _any_ situation where `a+b` would fail in JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

The test should be testing the result of the function. You can not access variables inside of a function since the varaibles scope is to the function block and it is not global.

You function should be returning the result from the function and your test should be testing what you expect the output to be.

```
function sum(a,b){
  var res = a + b;
  return res;
  // return a + b;
}
```

```
test('sum of numbers', () => {
  expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing implementation details like this is an anti-pattern in regards to frontend testing. You should be testing the user interaction that calls this function (eg. a button click). Then, check whether the rendered text on the screen is your desired result (ex. 1+1=2).

Project requirements that dictate a function is tested directly, are quite simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic test case for your sum function**

```
test('sum of numbers', () => {
expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3)
});
```

or you can use toEqual at the place of toBe.

Even you can check this post https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions for you. To get the res value, you can try using a reference type like a JavaScript object.

```js
function sum(a,b, obj){
  var res = a+b;
  obj.res = res;
  return true;
}

test('sum of numbers', () => {
  let obj = {};
  expect(sum(1, 2, obj)).toBe(true)

  expect(obj.res).toBe(5);
});
```

**OR**

Another option is to return an object from the function, which would include the boolean value you need to test, along with the internal variable.

```js
function sum(a,b){
  var res = a+b;
  return {
    res,
    val: true
  };
}

test('sum of numbers', () => {
  const {res, val} = sum(2, 3);
  expect(val).toBe(true)
  expect(res).toBe(5);
});
```

I noticed in one of your comments on a post that you mentioned

> Its a requirement in my project. I have to test an internal variable value inside a function

Just double checking, is it possible that the requirement is actually asking you to return the local variable and compare it, instead of a boolean? If so, you can follow the method outlined in [@epascarello's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75337808/14953535). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. The requirement is basically testing a function without a return value. So in this case I need to get the value of "res" (which is an internal variable) in the test file.

Comment: Then You can follow either the first or the second method